# How to use cut command in UNIX?

Tags: unix, cut

I have a really large text file (~80 Million records/lines), where each record has 7 attributes. Between every attribute there is a tab.

What I want to do is copy every third and last attribute/token of every record/line at a new file.

Any ideas how I could do that with the cut command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good starting point would be:

`cut -f 3,7 input.txt > output.txt`

If the file isn't tab delimited, you'll need to add a -d switch with the delimiter ( -d. would be a . delimited file).

Here are some examples, including grabbing multiple fields: http://linux.101hacks.com/linux-commands/cut-command-examples/

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: Is there any way I could cut specific rows based on the numerical value of some attributes? For example cut every row's 3 and 7 column but only if the fifth attribute < 5.